# How to add the two output of a PWM IC?

Tags: pwm, opto-isolator

[image]
I need to sum output A and output B of a PWM (UC3526AN) because each output have a maximum duty cycle of 0.45.

I try with 2 diode and a limiting resistor(R1) for the led inside the optocoupler (4N25)

This is the voltage before R1 
[image] 
This is the voltage after R1
[image]

- The blue line is the voltage to pin 1 .

This is the PWM block diagram :
[image]

Why did you think I got this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage "after R1" is a forward voltage drop on the optocoupler's internal LED, which is according to it's datasheet is around 1.5V. An this is roughly what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Use two resistors to sum the currents, although I suspect **you don't actually want this**:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYlKtd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But notice that summing the current to the LED in the optocoupler is different from OR-ing the on-time from the two PWMs.  When you OR (as in your schematic, with 2 diodes and 1 resistor) the LED in the optocoupler will turn on if either PWM is high.  When you sum, the LED will get 2x the current when both PWMs are high.

Since you're turning an optocoupler on and off, more current does not help.

Doubling the maximum duty cycle is trickier.  I would recommend one of two options:

1. if you want a wider range of possible duty cycles (e.g. 0 to 0.98), get a different PWM controller
2. if you want duty cycles from 0.55 to 0.9, invert your output

Comment: thanks, what i need is summing the voltage to get a make the optocoupler  on when it is high.